# How to use custom module AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, angular-module

how can I start to use this module: http://gregpike.net/demos/angular-local-storage/demo/demo.html
I have a controller:

```
app.controller('FormController', function ($scope, localStorageService) {

});
```

And I injected

```
localStorageService
```

as shown in example, but naturally nothing work. How can I fix it? Thanks.

Comment: what errors are thrown?

Comment: did you inject module dependency? Can't inject service in controller if module hasn't been injected

Comment: Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.12/$injector/unpr?p0=localStorageServiceProvider%20%3C-%20localStorageService%20%3C-%20FormController

Comment: @charlietfl, no I didn't do this, how can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you link the script from your page:

```
<script src=".../angular-local-storage.min.js"></script>
```

Second, you add the module to the module dependencies array (I guess that's what you missed):

```
angular.module('myApp', [..., 'LocalStorageModule', ...])
```

Then you can inject and use `localStorageService` in your components, as you did.

---

That said, I would add a step 0 : Read this [Readme](https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage#get-started) :)

Comment: oh...I did it, but now I can't use it in my controller: `localStorageService.set('goods', '3');`, I'm getting an error: `"Error: isUndefined is not defined
this.$get</addToLocalStorage@http://surprise.local/js/angular-local-storage.js:116:1
@http://surprise.local/js/app.js:34:13`

Comment: in my controller i injected: `app.controller('FormController', ["$scope", "localStorageService", function ($scope, localStorageService) {}]);`

Answer (score 0):

i recommend you this one https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage also use this syntax for not breaking whe you minify

```
app.controller('FormController', ["$scope", "otherProvider",function ($scope, otherProvider) {
//in this way angular know what to inject
}]);
```